# cocos2d,near-far

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am not an expert in cocos2d....as cocos2d draw a 2d graphics than how can anyone identify one object is nearer than another from viewer??

can anyone help me....i have basic opengl graphics idea....

thanks
Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a node to a parent, you can set its z order:

```
[scene addChild:aNode z:1];
```

A higher z order will be drawn first.

If you need to re-order a node after it's been added, you can call reorderChild:

```
[scene reorderChild:aNode z:3];
```